# Touch point on the near plane

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have a matrix created with either `orthoM` or `frustumM` GL function, where the near plane is logically the surface of the tablet. I would like to translate touch locations to their location on the near plane (that is, from device coordinates to the world coordinates).

I assume this is a common enough activity so I'm wondering if a standard API function exists (or simple sequence) which can provide me with this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at: [gluUnPoroject](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLU.html#gluUnProject%28float,%20float,%20float,%20float%5B%5D,%20int,%20float%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%5B%5D,%20int,%20float%5B%5D,%20int%29)

From the documentation:

> Map window coordinates to object coordinates. gluUnProject maps the
>   specified window coordinates into object coordinates using model,
>   proj, and view. The result is stored in obj.